# How to parse BMP header in C in easy (beginner friendly) way

Tags: c, parsing, bmp

I need to parse BMP header using the code below

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint16_t WORD;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef int32_t LONG;

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapfileheader
typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
  WORD  bfType;
  DWORD bfSize;
  WORD  bfReserved1;
  WORD  bfReserved2;
  DWORD bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER, *LPBITMAPFILEHEADER, *PBITMAPFILEHEADER;

// https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/previous-versions/dd183376(v=vs.85)
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER {
  DWORD biSize;
  LONG  biWidth;
  LONG  biHeight;
  WORD  biPlanes;
  WORD  biBitCount;
  DWORD biCompression;
  DWORD biSizeImage;
  LONG  biXPelsPerMeter;
  LONG  biYPelsPerMeter;
  DWORD biClrUsed;
  DWORD biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER, *LPBITMAPINFOHEADER, *PBITMAPINFOHEADER;
```

My goal is to print output in this way

```
  bfType:          0x4D42 (BM)
  bfSize:          369738
  bfReserved1:     0x0
  bfReserved2:     0x0
  bfOffBits:       138
```

I tried [Reading BMP file C++ (trouble with reading BMP header)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112412/reading-bmp-file-c-trouble-with-reading-bmp-header), but using `__attribute__((__packed__))` is confusing and changes the code I need to use.

I have the very beginning:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

    FILE * fPointer;
    fPointer = fopen(argv[1], "rb");  // read from file
```

However, I don't know how to store the 'HEADER' and 'INFO' in the structs declared above. Can someone help me with that step?

Comment: You are right, I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you need to read the file header. To do this, you need to write data to the structure that you have.
The information in the BMP file is saved in the same order as the variables in your structure.
It will be more correct to implement reading by creating a separate function that will return an already prepared structure with the data you need

```
BITMAPFILEHEADER *ReadBMFileHeader(FILE *fp)
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER *header = (BITMAPFILEHEADER *)malloc(sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    fread(&header.bfType, 2, 1, fp);
    fread(&header.bfSize, 4, 1, fp);
    fread(&header.bfReserve1, 2, 1, fp);
    fread(&header.bfReserve2, 2, 1, fp);
    fread(&header.bfOffBits, 4, 1, fp);
    return header;
}
```

So your main function gonna look like that:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fPointer = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    BITMAPFILEHEADER *bmFileHeader = NULL;
    bmFileHeader = ReadBMFileHeader(fPointer);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

To print data in HEX you can use this:

```
printf("%x\n", bmFileHeader->bfType);
```